# Terminal: extract same columns data and output into multiple files

Tags: file, awk, terminal

I have 30 files which every file has the same data structure, but for different observations. I want to extract the each file's first 4 columns data and then output each file's result into a new file. Therefore, I will have another 30 files which every file only contains original file's first 4 columns data.

I used the command line in Ubuntu. I used the following code, but I only got all outputs into a single file.

`awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}' File_*.txt > Part_File.txt`  ##I use the * to represent 01 to 30.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP needed output file as Output_file00 etc format so following may help you. Also if you have only 30 files to read then you could remove this `close(prev);prev=FILENAME` part, this will save you from `too many files opened` error in case you are reading n number of files by this code too.

```
awk 'FNR==1{close(out); out=sprintf("Output_%02d",++i)} {print $1, $2, $3, $4 > out}' File_*.txt
```

---

Since you haven't provided samples so couldn't test it, could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4 > ("Output_file"i)}' File_*.txt
```

Above should create Output_file(s) eg--> `Output_file1`, `Output_file2` and so on.

Comment: Many thanks! Your code works well and the outputs do have the form like: Output_file1, Output_file2 and so on. However, if I  hope the output has the prev like Output_file01, Output_02 and so on, what should I do?

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks a TON Ed sir I have changed it now. So it means whenever we edit a file then only we need to close a file it means? reading input_file(s) or putting data into output_file(s) will not cause the too many opened file issue? could you please guide.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure, `close(FILENAME)` was a mistake, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure done sir edited it. I really wonder how much knowledge do you have sir, hats off to you really :)